# ios didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge status

Tags: ios, nsurl

I'm trying to authenticate users through webserver and calling the following method in my login view button touch to do so.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"challenge failure %d", [challenge previousFailureCount]);

    // Access has failed two times...
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0)
    {
        //NSLog(@"desc %@",[connection description]);
        NSURLCredential *cred = [[[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:userName.text password:passWord.text
                                                           persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] autorelease];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        // need to call new view on correct authentication

            [connection release];

    }

    else {// Answer the challenge

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]


                              initWithTitle:@"Authentication error" 
                              message:@"Invalid Credentials" delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Retry"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];



    }

}
```

Is there any status returned after successful authentication so that i may use that status and pass on to next view else display the error.

Comment: You're not supposed to call that method manually, it's a callback when the host requires an authentication. Usually you setup an URL like `http://user:password@host.domain/...` and let it go.

Comment: YOu are right.. i actually meant while calling NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; I'm calling this in ibAction method when button is touched

Comment: Actually the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method tells you that you can proceed to the next step.

Comment: That is it dude.. I'm calling my new view from connectionDidFinishLoading: method and it works. If you can mention the above comment as an answer i'll mark it as accepted.. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as said in my comment:

Actually the connectionDidFinishLoading: method tells you that you can proceed to the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Jsut Call connectionDidFinishLoading: Method.